# Get only url value of FileStack JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, json, url, info

I'm using FileStack on my website, according to FileStack Docs I have this actually:

```
<iframe id="framefile" width="700" height="500" frameborder="0">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
<div id="files"></div>
```

And in javascript side:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.filepicker.io/v2/filepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
filepicker.setKey("myAPIKey");
filepicker.pickMultiple(
  {
    mimetype: '*/*',
    language: 'es_mx',
    container: 'framefile',
    services: ['COMPUTER','GOOGLE_DRIVE','DROPBOX']
  },
  function(Blobs){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Blobs));
  },
  function(FPError){
    console.log(FPError.toString());
  });
  </script>
```

I need to get only URL files values and put it in a div. I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
filepicker.setKey("myAPIKey");
filepicker.pickMultiple(
  {
    mimetype: '*/*',
    language: 'es_mx',
    container: 'framefile',
    services: ['COMPUTER','GOOGLE_DRIVE','DROPBOX']
  },
  function(Blobs){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Blobs));
    var result = JSON.stringify(Blobs, ['url']);
    $('#files').html(result);
  },
  function(FPError){
    console.log(FPError.toString());
  });
</script>
```

I obtain this:

> [{"url":"https://cdn.filepicker.io/api/file/--link1--"}]

But How can I obtain URL values but in this way?:

> https://cdn.filepicker.io/api/file/--link1--

Anyone have a solution?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(Blobs)[0].url;` or else you have to parse first by `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, are not you?

What about appending `[0].url` to the object which is returned ?

I mean substituting `result = JSON.stringify(Blobs, ['url']);` for `result = JSON.stringify(Blobs, ['url'])[0].url`;

**UPDATE**

My first anwser is wrong because `result` in

```
result = JSON.stringify(Blobs, ['url'])
```

returns `'[{"url":"https://cdn.filepicker.io/api/file/--link1--"}]'`, which is a string since it comes from a `stringify`ed variable. Thus, `result[0]` returns its first character, which is `"["`. Finaly `result[0].url` or put differently, `"[".url` is undefined. (and can hardly be so)

Replace this part:

```
function(Blobs){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Blobs));
    var result = JSON.stringify(Blobs, ['url']);
    $('#files').html(result);
}
```

by

```
function(Blobs){
    $('#files').html(Blobs[0].url);
}
```

If one wants to get the desired information from a json, one must not `stringify` it.

**Update**

Or if you want to display numerous urls, because of multiple files replace the latter method by

```
function(Blobs){
    var displayedUrls = "";
    for (i = 0; i < Blobs.length; i++) { 
        displayedUrls += Blobs[i].url + "<br>";
    }
}
$('#files').html(displayedUrls);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but I tried in that way and it shows nothing

Comment: @NekoLopez try this.

Comment: That is great! But what happen if I upload more than one file? I will always get only one url of the first file that I selected but not the rest of URL files.

Comment: Thank you very much!! you are a genius! :D!