# Doesn't get values of JSON in Filestack v3

Tags: javascript, json, url, filepicker, info

I'm trying with Filestack (Filepicker) V3 to upload multiple files and get filename, url and mimetype. So according to Filestack docs for this new release and following [a similar question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871861/get-only-url-value-of-filestack-json-stringify) I have this:

```
var client = filestack.init('myapikey');
    client.pick({
      accept: 'image/*',
      fromSources: ['local_file_system','googledrive','gmail','facebook','dropbox','onedrive','webcam'],
      maxFiles: 5,
      imageMax: [1024, 1024]
    }).then(function(Blobs) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(Blobs));

      var result = "";
      for(var i=0; i<Blobs.length; i++){
        result+=Blobs[i].filename + " : " + Blobs[i].url + " : " + Blobs[i].mimetype;
      }
      alert(result);

    });
```

For example I upload 2 files, in console the result is like:

```
{"filesUploaded":[{"filename":"diploma1.jpg","handle":"1e3CkeZQaeokzS9TpcJM","mimetype":"image/jpeg","originalPath":"diploma1.jpg","size":258169,"source":"local_file_system","url":"https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/1e3CkeZQaeokzS9TpcJM","originalFile":{"customName":"diploma1.jpg"},"status":"Stored"},{"filename":"diploma2.jpg","handle":"kOejeHySTSG0TuSJWWlh","mimetype":"image/jpeg","originalPath":"diploma2.jpg","size":31072,"source":"local_file_system","url":"https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/kOejeHySTSG0TuSJWWlh","originalFile":{"customName":"diploma2.jpg"},"status":"Stored"}],"filesFailed":[]}
```

But alert shows no result and I want to get alert result like this:

```
diploma1.jpg : https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/1e3CkeZQaeokzS9TpcJM : image/jpeg
diploma2.jpg : https://cdn.filestackcontent.com/kOejeHySTSG0TuSJWWlh : image/jpeg
```

I would like some help.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for some information about result console and based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577172/how-to-get-json-objects-value-if-its-name-contains-dots) I modified my code to finally get my result:

```
var client = filestack.init('myapikey');
    client.pick({
      accept: 'image/*',
      fromSources: ['local_file_system','googledrive','gmail','facebook','dropbox','onedrive','webcam'],
      maxFiles: 5,
      imageMax: [1024, 1024]
    }).then(function(Blobs) {

      console.log(JSON.stringify(Blobs));
      var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Blobs));

      var res = "";

      for(var i=0; i<result.filesUploaded.length; i++){
        res+=result.filesUploaded[i].filename + " : " + result.filesUploaded[i].url + " : " + result.filesUploaded[i].mimetype + "\n";
      }

      alert(res);

    });
```

:)